# Translate mysql_field_name into mysqli object

Tags: php, xml

How can i translate this into the mysqli object oriented version?

mysql_field_name($result, $i);

I tried $result->field_name($i); with no result

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 1):

[mysqli_result::fetch_field](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-field.php) OR [mysqli_result::fetch_fields](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-fields.php)